# How can I return from a shell script and then reboot (to use with VirtualBox)?

Tags: bash, shell, virtualbox, restart

I am using guestcontrol with Virtual Box with a Windows host and a Linux (RHEL7) guest. I want to do some config from the host to the guest by running a shell script on the guest (from a .bat on the host). This is fine and the script runs, however, it hangs when I call the reboot (I believe it is because nothing is returned). So when the following .sh is called:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "here"
exit
```

The .bat file shows "here" and then exits (or if I use pause gives the correct message). However, when I add the reboot, the .bat never processes anything past where it calls the script. I think this would be because the guest never tells the host that the script is complete.

I have tried things like:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ sleep 1; reboot; } >/dev/null &
exit
```

or even:

```
#!/bin/bash
do_reboot(){
  sleep 1
  reboot
}
do_reboot() &
exit
```

but the .bat never gets past the line where it runs the .sh

How can I tell the host that the .sh script (on the guest) is complete so it can continue with the .bat script?

Comment: Try `(sleep 5; reboot)&` then `exit` That run `sleep` and `reboot` from a subshell which will give you `5` seconds to exit the script, cleanup and disconnect before the `reboot` occurs.

Comment: Nope, does the same thing. The .bat never gets past the script as though the script is hanging.

Comment: Hmmm. There must be something strange about executing from the windoze side of things with a *.bat* file. That's the exact way I do it *nix* to *nix* on a daily basis. Good luck, make sure the answer is posted, I'm curious now too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to make sure there are no sub processes running, so we want to do a no heads up using the nohup command. So the script simply becomes this:

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup reboot &> /tmp/nohup.out </dev/null &
exit
```

The stdin and stdout were causing the issues, so this just sends them into the void so that the script will not be waiting for any input from any other processes.

If you have any issues with this script, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup /path/to/reboot_delay.sh &> /tmp/nohup.out </dev/null &
exit
```

And then in /path/to/reboot_delay.sh you would have:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10 # or however many seconds you need to wait for something to happen
reboot
```

This way you could even allow some time for something to finish etc, yet the host machine (or ssh or wherever you are calling this from) would still know the script had finished and do what it needs to do.

I hope this can help people in future.

Comment: I wonder, if the need to handle the standard streams doesn't have something to do with the virtualbox interface (guest additions, etc..) that enable copy/paste, mouse, etc.. from windoze. I've always run virtualbox the other way around (linux host, windows guest), and usually headless via the VBoxManage commands. Glad you got it working, and thanks for the heads up.